# Relating the three forms of the simple group of order 25920

Tags: finite-groups

There is a unique simple group of order 25920. It has three main forms that I am aware of
$$
B_2(3) \cong C_2(3) \cong  \; ^2A_3(2^2)
$$
equivalently
$$
O(5,3) \cong PSp(4,3) \cong PSU(4,2)
$$
It is well known that $ B_2(q) \cong C_2(q) $ in other words $ O(5,q)\cong PSp(4,q) $. So the first isomorphism is just this for the case $ q=3 $.

However I would like to better understand the isomorphisms $ PSp(4,3) \cong PSU(4,2) $ and $ O(5,3) \cong PSU(4,2) $. Is there any nice geometric way to see this, for example by seeing these groups as the symmetries of related objects ?

To be honest I don't even know much about the $ O(5,q) \cong PSp(4,q) $ isomorphism so if someone thinks that explaining that more or providing a helpful reference would help then I would certainly appreciate that as well.

for example something like this:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348110/geometric-interpretation-of-the-exceptional-isomorphism-psp4-3-psu4-22?rq=1